# How to convert input numpy data to tensorflow tf.data to train model in tensorfow?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, image-classification, data-science-model

I am working on an image classification problem using TensorFlow. I have converted my input image dataset and label into NumPy data but it takes more time and more ram to load all the data into memory because I have 90K images. I would like to use TensorFlow data API using [tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_director](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory)

Here's my current code to train NumPy data. I want to convert this code into tf.data(tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_director) to train my huge dataset.

```
INIT_LR = 1e-4
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the input image (224x224) and preprocess it
    image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays
data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of
# the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the MobileNetV2 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are
# left off
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving mask detector model...")
model.save(args["model"], save_format="h5")
```

Comment: Don't read the data from the Directory, just pass the path of the parent directory to the function. Read [here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `flow_from_directory()` method on your `ImageDataGenerator` class, which does the augmentation - only a small change is necessary:

```
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow_from_directory(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    ...)
```

If you start using a [**`tf.data.Dataset`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) directly, you will get more control over how the data is read from disk (caching, number of threads etc.), but you will lose the easy image augmentation you get with the `ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: The main problem is when i loop over the image paths to read all images it takes more time and more memory .

`for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the input image (224x224) and preprocess it
    image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)`

i want to remove this line.

Comment: If you use the `flow_from_directory` method, you don't need to loop over the files at all, that happens automatically during training! You can set the target image size as a parameter to that method. I don't know what you do in YOUR `process_input` function - you might need to find another way to do that, e.g. wrapping the generator in your own generator ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972618/how-to-modify-flow-from-directory-or-preprocessing-function-in-imagedatagenerato)), or adding a Lambda layer before your model's first layer.